# How do I soft credit a pledge?

Tags: civicontribute, pledges, soft-credit

If Jane Doe donates $1000 by the efforts of John Q. Public, I can soft credit John.  However, if Jane pledges $1000 in 10 monthly installments, there's no built-in way to credit John automatically as those pledges are made.  Has anyone encountered this solution and solved it?

Note: I'm the author of the [Automatic Soft Credits](https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.module.automaticsoftcredit) extension, this is not the correct answer :)

Comment: I also have this question. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I also have this question. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10569)